# Input string[] into TypeScript ...string pipe parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I'm creating an Angular application. I've created a pipe with a variable number of input parameters defined like this:

```
transform(value: string, ...parameterValues: string[]): string {
  // Code to be executed
}
```

I'm using this pipe from HTML with a `string[]` containing my parameter values:

```
{{ message | pipe : params}}
```

The problem is that typescript is complaining:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

How can I input this variable number of parameters into my pipe?

Comment: You can't, as far as I'm aware Angular template syntax doesn't provide any "spread" equivalent for arrays to separate pipe arguments. You could rewrite the pipe to accept a single parameter, which is an array of strings (presumably what `params` is).

Comment: Rewriting pipe to accept array. Of course. Thanks!